# Java - repetitive hmacSHA1 hashing - how to convert to PHP?

Tags: java, php, hmacsha1

How do you convert the following Java to PHP?

```
byte[] byteArray1 = key1.getBytes("UTF8");
byte[] byteArray2 = key2.getBytes("UTF8");
byte[] byteArray3 = key3.getBytes("UTF8");
byte[] byteArray4 = key4.getBytes("UTF8");

Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
SecretKeySpec derivedKey = new SecretKeySpec(byteArray1, "HmacSha1");
mac.init(derivedKey); derivedKey = new SecretKeySpec(mac.doFinal(byteArray2), "HmacSha1"); }
mac.init(derivedKey); derivedKey = new SecretKeySpec(mac.doFinal(byteArray3), "HmacSha1");
mac.init(derivedKey); derivedKey = new SecretKeySpec(mac.doFinal(byteArray4), "HmacSha1");
```

From all the research I've done, it looks like **if we'd remove the last two lines**, we could neatly convert it to PHP as follows:

```
hash_hmac("sha1", $key2, $key1, true);
```

**However, how to you convert this type of reiterative hashing to PHP?**

*Note: I've tried the following unsuccessfully:*

```
$derivedKey = hash_hmac("sha1", $key2, $key1, true);
$derivedKey = hash_hmac("sha1", $key3, $derivedKey, true);
$derivedKey = hash_hmac("sha1", $key4, $derivedKey, true);
```

Comment: You say it looks like it should be the same. Have you actually tried it with the single call of `mac.init()`?

Comment: @Phylogenesis, I'm unable to modify the Java... I just have to create PHP code that gives me the same derivedKey

Comment: You could just write a simple program for testing purposes.